# How to enable curl extension on wamp?

Tags: php

I am using appache2.2.22 and php5.3.13. I tried removing comment on curl_extension on php.ini file.But no change that curl is not enabled.I stucks with that for some days.How can i enable this?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

If its Wamp Server, left click on Wamp Server icon from system tray -> click PHP -> PHP Extensions -> click php_curl.

Wamp will then restart it's self. After it restarts check it is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with cURL in php 5.3.13 in the 64 bit version.

Fortunately, there is a fix which you can download here: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ (download the Fixed curl version)

Glad you can stop losing time with this annoying problem :)